# Docker different digest when push same images with different tags

Tags: docker

I built one docker image with one tag and then tag it with a new tag (both tags include registry URL).

I push the first tag, then the second tag, the push digest from 2 tags are different:

```
16:10:47 + docker build -t 10.88.102.47:8443/my-project/foo:jenkins-305 .
...
16:11:26 + docker tag 10.88.102.47:8443/my-project/foo:jenkins-305 10.88.102.47:8443/my-project/foo:latest

16:11:26 + docker push 10.88.102.47:8443/my-project/foo:jenkins-305
...
16:11:34 jenkins-280: digest: sha256:22a4cd54bf43f03530c475832ca4432adfcf02c796e9c1cdafea72cf07ce7bf4 size: 3654

16:11:35 + docker push 10.88.102.47:8443/my-project/foo:latest
...
16:11:36 latest: digest: sha256:ccb4e8c41339b1a5d780cc5d28064cabf839657617a9c1e1d14eaee507405b20 size: 3632
```

Pushing tag `jenkins-305` - digest `22a4cd54bf43f03530c475832ca4432adfcf02c796e9c1cdafea72cf07ce7bf4`

Pushing tag `latest` - digest `ccb4e8c41339b1a5d780cc5d28064cabf839657617a9c1e1d14eaee507405b20`

Shouldn't 2 digests of 2 tags from same image identical?

**Update**

I downloaded both tags on a different machines and see those tags have the same `IMAGE ID` (digest?)

```
10.88.102.47:8443/my-project/foo   jenkins-305      sha256:5537979d74ac00f75b7830c41c27be5f545ec55b0ab12622f9fad2eec8583a6e   21 minutes ago      689.2 MB
10.88.102.47:8443/my-project/foo   latest           sha256:5537979d74ac00f75b7830c41c27be5f545ec55b0ab12622f9fad2eec8583a6e   21 minutes ago      689.2 MB
```

But this digest is different from the digest provided by `docker push`, why?

Answer (score 5):

The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) on the registry report that the digest contains the image manifest, and the manifest is made up of the tag amongst other things.

Comment: Can you explain more details? I found somewhat similar thread: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1662 but not sure if its related.